# How to find the storage space available in Google Drive from a web application?

Tags: google-drive-api, drive

I want to create a web application in which the application will check for the available drive space on that user's account and then upload the file on their google drive. Can anyone please suggest some code snippet or any other useful link for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a simple app in Google Scripts that returns the available space in Drive using the [DriveApp service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app).

- DriveApp.getStorageLimit() - Gets the number of bytes the user is
  allowed to store in Drive.
- DriveApp.getStorageUsed() - Gets the number of bytes the user is
  currently storing in Drive.

Answer (score 0):

Get the about resource https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get and check the resulting https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about#resource

Answer (score -1):

Uploading a file:

```
function uploadFiles() {

  try {

    var dropbox = getFolderById("your file");
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var pic = DriveApp.addFile(your_pic); //your picture   
    var file = folder.createFile(pic);    

  } catch (error) {

    return error.toString();
  }

}
```